# Circuit on weighted multigraph

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am solving the Chinese Postman Problem on a tennis court, and I would like to plot the circuit in Tikz if possible. I know how to plot the circuit if I simply have a graph, but the modified graph I obtain when solving the Chinese Postman Problem is a multigraph.

The tour that I obtain is (1,12),(12,11),(11,3),(3,4),(4,5),(5,6),(6,7), (7,8),(8,4),(4,8),(8,9),(9,10),(10,9),(9,11),(11,3),(3,2),(2,1)

My TikZ code for just representing the graph is as follows:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt, auto, node distance=3cm, thick,
   edge_style/.style={draw=black, thick}]

   \foreach [count=\i] \x/\y/\t in {-2/-2/2, -1/-2/3, 4/3/6, 3/-2/4, 4/-2/5, -2/3/1, 3/3/7, 3/0.7/8, 1/0.7/9, 1/3/10, -1/0.7/11, -1/3/12}
     \node [shape=circle,inner sep=2pt,draw,thick,font=\sffamily\small]
        (v\i) at (\x,\y) {\t};

   \foreach \i/\j/\t in {1/2/4.5, 2/4/27, 1/6/39, 5/4/4.5, 5/3/39, 4/8/21, 8/7/18, 8/9/13.5, 9/10/18, 9/11/13.5, 11/2/21, 11/12/18}
    \draw [edge_style]  (v\i) edge node{\t} (v\j);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I would like to just change `\draw[edge_style]` to `\draw[->, >=latex]`, but this does not go well with creating multiedges, since they need to arc from `node` to `node`.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: [is this what you want?](http://i.stack.imgur.com/sCbLb.png) Although, I'm not sure what you mean by "they need to arc".

Comment: @Alenanno yeah that's very close, thank you. When I mean by arc, is the fact that I travel from node to node twice: For example, I go from 9 to 10 then back from 10 to 9 using two edges both connecting 9 and 10 if that makes sense. By "arcing" I just meant, that the drawing should distinguish between them, so that I essentially walk twice between those two nodes. Anyway, thanks very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `edge` options `bend left/right`, and even input a degree like `bend left=10`.

The nodes one the arrows have been reduced in size to fit better with the graph.

I have added another variable `\xi` using the command `count`, and starting from 1, it adds 1 to each element in the `\foreach`, basically setting an index number to each item in the list.

Then moved the 3 exceptions to the first three of your foreach, so that they all were close together, `1 2 3`. Then added an `if` statement, which is really self-explanatory.

**Edit**

Since you wanted another exception, I moved the exception to the position `3`, so I nested another `\ifnum` and now it checks if the number is below `3`, if it's `3` and everything else, in that order.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt, auto, node distance=3cm, thick,
   edge_style/.style={-{Latex}}]

   \foreach [count=\i] \x/\y/\t in {-2/-2/2, -1/-2/3, 4/3/6, 3/-2/4, 4/-2/5, -2/3/1, 3/3/7, 3/0.7/8, 1/0.7/9, 1/3/10, -1/0.7/11, -1/3/12}
     \node [shape=circle,inner sep=2pt,draw,thick,font=\sffamily\small]
        (v\i) at (\x,\y) {\t};

    \foreach \i/\j/\t [count=\xi starting from 1] in {9/10/18, 4/8/21, 11/2/21, 1/2/4.5, 2/4/27, 1/6/39, 5/4/4.5, 5/3/39, 8/7/18, 8/9/13.5, 9/11/13.5, 11/12/18}{
    \ifnum\xi<3
        \draw [edge_style]  (v\i) edge[bend left=10] (v\j);
        \draw [edge_style]  (v\j) edge[bend left=10] node[midway, font=\scriptsize]{\t} (v\i);
    \else
        \ifnum\xi=3
            \draw [edge_style]  (v\i) edge[bend left=10] (v\j);
            \draw [edge_style]  (v\i) edge[bend right=10] node[left, midway, font=\scriptsize]{\t} (v\j);
        \else
            \draw [edge_style]  (v\i) -- node[midway, font=\scriptsize]{\t} (v\j);
        \fi
    \fi
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This looks like what I need, but I only need some of my arrows to bend. Basically, (3,11), (9,10) and (4,8). Do I simply make two different \foreach loops, if at all possible?

Comment: @ThePuix Yes, it is possible and with a single `\foreach`. Just a moment. :)

Comment: @ThePuix See edit.

Comment: This is so awesome! Thank you so much! Dont have enough reputation to upvote :/, but I can accept your answer.

Comment: @ThePuix No problem! :D

Comment: sorry to ping you so much later, but I realised that I needed to have both arrows going between 11 and 3 to both point from 11 to 3. I couldn't find the appropriate modification myself, so I am once again callin upon your services ;)

Comment: @ThePuix Sure, that's fairly easy. See edit, is that it?